# Eclipse-PMD : error while installing through eclipse market place

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd, eclipse-kepler

I'm trying to install the PMD source code analyser plugin for Eclipse. It's available through Eclipse Market Place, but I'm getting following problem in the phase of installation :

[image]

Why am I getting this problem ?

**EDIT**
I do not have this menu even though I have added the ruleset configuration file
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the creator of eclipse-pmd, the plugin you are trying to install. I tried to install it myself just now and it worked without any problems. So I can only guess what could be the problem in your case:

**The repository was temporarily not available**
Simply try again.

**You are using a (very) old version of Eclipse**
The plugin requires Eclipse Indigo (3.7) or later. I tried to install eclipse-pmd with Indigo and Luna just now and it worked both times.

**Run Eclipse with Java 7**
You need to run Eclipse with a JRE 7 or later. There have been problems during the installation with people using an older JRE in the past. However they could finish the installation but Eclipse silently refused to load the plugin (this has been fixed a few versions ago though).

**Proxy configuration**
Although unlikely as you came this far, please open the proxy configuration in Eclipse and check if the settings are correct and the domain is accessible.

If you tried everything I suggested above and are still not able to install the plugin, please head over to the project's Github page and [open an issue](https://github.com/acanda/eclipse-pmd/issues).

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Kepler :) Well after checking, the installation ended quite normally, But after restarting I can't see PMD in Windows->Preferences nor in Windows->show perspective (the jars are present in directory_of_eclipse/plugins)

Comment: You can activate PMD in the project properties. There is a short "Getting Started Guide" at the eclipse-pmd website: http://acanda.github.io/eclipse-pmd/getting-started.html

Comment: It's Ok But when I do right click on the projet for analysing, the PMD option doesn't appear on the list

Comment: There is no PMD menu item because once you configure and enable PMD for a project the plugin automatically analyses the source code when you save a file. This keeps the PMD warnings always up to date.

Comment: Ok thank you very much sir :) between do you have any good tutorial about whats is a rule set ? and how can I add one ? I'm completely new to PMD

Comment: In the Edit in the question, there is a picture of the screen of one of friends having PMD working succesfully

Comment: Your friend is using a different PMD plugin. With eclipse-pmd you don't need those menu items as it automatically analyses the code.
The PMD website has a page explaining [how to make a rulset](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/customizing/howtomakearuleset.html).